# Get Jump status after Jump to bootloader from Application

Tags: arm, microcontroller, nxp-microcontroller

I'm using LPC845 Cortext M0+ chip. I'm able to jump from bootloader to application and application to bootloader. Once the microcontroller is power on first time it check whether application is present or not, if application is present is jump to application. When I would like to jump back to bootloader i'm using the same logic to jump to bootloader and it works well.

Now I would like to perform some specific task if bootloader is execute from application.

Is there any best way to check whether bootloader execution start from application or it is normal power on execution?

I may use the same technique to multiple controller so kindly suggest best way to perform above task

Comment: too broad please provide more detail and some code.

Comment: could not say for sure about LPC845, but most controllers has a special register which indicates type of 'startup'. eg power up, reset, soft reset... And I'm surprised by your approach to call a bootloader from an app. To access bootloader, I'd do soft reset. That trigger start sequence and at the same time preserve pretty much all controller states and memory

Comment: In bootloader I'm checking if application is present or not if yes it jumps to application otherwise it stay at bootloader and wait for application to update. Here if I do reset from application it jumps back to application because it is present in memory and my problem not solve as I have to do some operation if it is execute from application.  I think I can achieve this by reserve common RAM memory for bootloader and application. Of course that area should not be initialized while startup.